# Closed hyperbolic manifolds with $b_1 = 1$

Tags: differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, betti-numbers

Are there examples of closed hyperbolic $n$-manifolds $M$ that have the first Betti number equal to one, $b_1(M) = 1$, such that $n \geq 4$?

---

I am aware that there are such examples for $n = 3$, using the Thurston-Nielsen classification and the abundance of pseudo-Anosov maps on surfaces with prescribed action on $H^1$. According to B. Martelli (see below) there is an example with $n = 4$ and $b_1(M) = 2$, called the ``Conder–Maclachlan manifold".

*Martelli, Bruno*, Hyperbolic four-manifolds,  [ZBL07034448](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:07034448).

Comment: Is there a reason you are asking about dimension 4 and $b_1=1$? Why not dimension 99 and $b_1=0$, or $b_1=1$, or $b_1=17$? That, I am sure, is unknown.

Comment: My motivation is given by looking at the dimension of the space of generalised Policott-Ruelle resonance states at zero, in the bundle of differential 1-forms as is computed recently in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.01010.pdf . Dimension three is special, as shown in the paper, that's why $n \geq 4$ ($n=2$ clearly doesn't work). For some reason which I don't want to get into now, I would like this dimension to be exactly one. I hope someone (experts) could have an idea if such a claim is true.

Comment: Then my suggestion is to write to some people directly (Martelli, Ratcliffe, Tschantz) and ask about such 4-d example.  By Millson's theorem, there are examples with positive $b_1$ in all dimensions $n\ge 4$, but there are only few examples where Betti numbers are explicitly known.